# Cordova project doesn't build after installing Plugins

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have a cordova project created in VS2015 *(which works fine if theres no plugin)*, i was looking to install 2 plugins.

Splashscreen plugin and Admobpro

While installing Splashscreen plugin it says "Plugin couldnt be downloaded"

and for Admobpro, it takes year to install *(then i installed it locally)*, but after I installed the plugin, 
the project dosnt build

Projects builds fine, if I remove the plugins

*(excuse me for the English)*

Comment: Well I don't have experience with VS but maybe I can help. Have you tried building from CLI? If "locally installed" plugin entry is present in `cordova plugin` listing?

Comment: file structure of cordova project created with vs2015 is a little with different as compared to the project crated with CLI .. it may not build with CLI ?

Comment: The best options is to try it out. Start with `cordova build <platform> --verbose` and watch for some information. With `--verbose` you can see valuable informations such as looping in plugin installation process or other things. In case of your problem: are you sure that plugins supports platform you are building for?

Comment: thank you so much for your support.. i worked after I changed the CLI version inside the project ..

Answer (score 1):

I  just switched the CLI version from 4.0.1 to 5.0.4, and it worked.

I dont know the actual reason, but just posting it here may be it could be helpful for someone else in the future

Comment: 5.* is still quite old. The current version is 6.4.0.
BTW: with `npm -g outdated`, you get all global npm packages for which an update is available.